# C# - AES first block decrypt TransformBlock return 0 bytes

Tags: c#, aes, block

I am creating a file encryption and decryption program.
Since I need access to the encrypted and decrypted data during the encryption and decryption process, I cannot use CryptoStream.

Therefore, I am forced to use TransformBlock and TransformFinalBlock on the ICryptoTransform interface.

I have no issues with encryption, but when it comes to decryption, I'm experiencing this strange behavior.

I have a byte[] buffer filled with a block of encrypted data. When calling decryptor.TransformBlock, the resulting plaintext is all zeros.
I have read that ICryptoTransform uses an internal buffer, and I understand that this method returns 0 on the first call.

How can I correctly use decryptor.TransformBlock with a buffer of blocks to decrypt?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
byte[] ret = new byte[blockSize];

int start = 0;
int length = blockSize;

int count = decryptor.TransformBlock(buffer, start, length, ret, 0);
```

count is 0 for the first block (buffer)

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you close the decryptor after? You may need to do this to "flush" the data to the buffer.

Comment: The problem seems to be here

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rijndaelmanagedtransform.cs,237


How to deal with this code ?
Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with that behaviour? If you get `0` then no bytes were written, os just loop round again. Then do the `TransformFinalBlock` at the end.

Comment: loop round with the same first block or with the second block ? 
This is not the role of IV ?
Thanks